# How to disable antd css-dev-only styles

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css, antd

I have a **nextjs** project with **tailwind** and **antd**.
When I use antd Layout component this styling is applied and I cant remove it.

```
:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-12upa3x).ant-layout-header
```

it's coming from a style script from head:

```
<style data-rc-order="prependQueue" data-css-hash="twrzxg" data-token-hash="vx5xn4" data-dev-cache-path="vx5xn4|Shared|ant">:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-12upa3x) a{color:#1677ff;text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent;outline:none;cursor:pointer;transition:color 0.3s;-webkit-text-decoration-skip:objects;}:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-12upa3x) a:hover{color:#69b1ff;}:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-12upa3x) a:active{color:#0958d9;}:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-12upa3x) a:active,:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-12upa3x) a:hover{text-decoration:none;outline:0;}:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-12upa3x) a:focus{text-decoration:none;outline:0;}:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-12upa3x) a[disabled]{color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);cursor:not-allowed;}</style>
```

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can disable it from the theme config:

```
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';

<ConfigProvider theme={{ hashed: false }}>
  <App />
</ConfigProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use the `<StyleProvider>` [as outlined here](https://ant.design/docs/react/compatible-style). I've had a bit of a time getting this to work with the *single* component that I'm using from ant design, this is what I finally came up with:

```
import { StyleProvider } from '@ant-design/cssinjs';
...
<StyleProvider hashPriority="high"><TimePicker /></StyleProvider>
```

In my experience, the StyleProvider needs to be the root element in the component.